# How do you insert HTML into a C# Program?

Tags: c#, html

I need help here. I am trying to create a program that allows users to listen to the radio from a site I work on, without actually getting on the site. I have created the page I need it to display, but I am having trouble getting it to display in the Forms Application.
This is the page it needs to display:

If anyone could help me, that'd be great. Thanks in advance, even though I will probably say it again. 
http://pastebin.com/0cSLMHht

Comment: you need to show the page you created in a windows form application ? or in a browser ?

Comment: In the windows forms application. But if that is impossible, I can use the browser.

Comment: I don't get your question. Anybody else ? I suggest you to write in more detail so that 3rd person who never saw your code can understand what you are talking about

Answer (score 2):

Please use the Windows WebBrowser Control for it

see link here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx

Examples are here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2te2y1x6

Comment: @Ume please see the link on my answer

Comment: Where do I put this? this.webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.microsoft.com");

Comment: @CodyLeeKaczynski its a windows control so DnD on the Form from the toolBox

Comment: Errors.. http://prntscr.com/c6otb

Comment: @CodyLeeKaczynski I am off now but can you put your code print screen for me pls

Comment: http://prntscr.com/c6pjs

Comment: @CodyLeeKaczynski you need to put this this.webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.microsoft.com"); inside a Button_Click event

Comment: But I want it to open automatically. Like, as the program opens.

Comment: @CodyLeeKaczynski the control gives the option to show HTML in windows form and the behaviour you want will require custom logic as per your requirements

Comment: Alright. What is the code for button click event?

Comment: easiest way is to drop a button on your form and double click it will take you inside the click event fo the button